# Code is beeing skipped in Window_Loaded WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

For some reason my some of my code seems to get skipped without throwing an error.
Im writing a program for school that uses a combobox with every word in the bible that searches a bible for the word thats clicked on and outputs every verse that contains that word to a listbox. 
The code that gets skipped is the forloop and output. (apperantly)
Further info:
Wordsinthebible.length = about 33000
Verses in the Bible.length = about 24000

Here is the relevant code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Read bible
        bible = File.ReadAllText("../../LUTHER.TXT", Encoding.UTF7);
        VersesInTheBible = File.ReadAllLines("../../LUTHER.TXT", Encoding.UTF7);

        //"Suchwort" is just a class that saves a string(the word) and a string array(the verses)
        WordsToSearch = new List<Suchwort>();

        //Split bible in to words
        WordsInTheBible = new List<string>(GetWords(bible).Distinct());
        WordsInTheBible.Sort();

        //Fill list with word and verses
        for (int i = 0; i < WordsInTheBible.Count; i++)
        {
            WordsToSearch.Add(new Suchwort(WordsInTheBible[i], GetVerses(WordsInTheBible[i])));
        }

        //Give combobox Words to search by
        cbx_wörter.ItemsSource = WordsToSearch;
    }

    public string[] GetVerses(string wort)
    {
        List<string> Verse = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < VersesInTheBible.Length; i++)
        {
            if (VersesInTheBible[i].Contains(wort))
            {
                Verse.Add(VersesInTheBible[i]);
            }
        }
        return Verse.ToArray();
    }
```

Now what happens when i run the program is it doesn't crash or throw any exception but all i get is an empty combobox:

[image: empty combobox]

Am I looping for too long through all the words and verses or should that be OK?

Comment: Have you stepped through it with debugger?  What does `GetWords()` do?

Comment: What happens when you step through the code in debug mode?

Comment: Are you looping through them at all?

Comment: Show your xaml code.

Comment: Looks like a bad `DisplayMember` value in the combo box. Show the XAML, that is where your problem is.

Comment: Errors in `Loaded` event are not thrown. You need to step though your code.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain agreed. Must be one specified.  I think otherwise it would just say `cbx_worter.Suchwort` for each one.  A misspelling would just show a blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but all i get is an empty combobox:

That is because the program is loading the combobox with 24,000 items on the GUI Thread and due to the huge performance hit the GUI is taking, one never seea any items.

The standard recommendation is to only do labor intensive work in a background thread/process and when done provide the item to a `ViewModel` property which via `InotifyPropertyChange` that data is ready to be shown. While the process is running alert the user to the long running process by using a [WPF BusyIndicator](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpf-busyindicator/).

---

Frankly no one will ever use a 24000 word drop down. It is just not feasible. I recommend you put in an edit box with a button to initiate a search. When the user pushes the button provide a *managable* list of items to select based on the TextBox data.

---

If MVVM is new check out my blog article [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017) to get you started.

Comment: So if i understood correctly there is too much going on in Window_Loaded which leads to WPF saying screw it? I guess i will have a look into Viewmodels thanks for the info and link.

Comment: @ThatBrianDude, yes too much is going on. For now, hard code the drop down to three items and see the speed difference.